# How can autorouting be done in Altium CircuitMaker?

Tags: pcb-design, altium, ddr, autorouter, circuitmaker

I need to do autorouting in Altium CircuitMaker. I have only found information how to do autorouting in Altium Designer.

What I need to know is to set up rules and enviroment for autorouting with the same length. This image shows a DDR3-memory and that requries the same length for all tracks.

Sure, I can drag every track by hand....but it would take a month.

[image]

Comment: You my need to implement a design rule where nets must ne the same length. Details on that here: https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/length-tuning-pcb ... What you would probably do is autoroute then make any adjustments.

Comment: What do the plethora of altium support sites say about this? Have you done your research?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: You don't.

Long answer: You don't do this in Circuit Maker at all and you even don't let Altium's autorouter work in AD (all versions including the most current AD24). The state of Altium's autorouter is abysmal.

Comment: So autoroute is bad ?

Comment: Altium's Autoroute is unusable. I have yet to find a decent autorouter which could do the things you want in less time than manually and I've been in this business for ~20 years. The best one I've come across was Specctra but that was 10 years ago or so.

Comment: Thank you Tom L!